# Как связать две страницы на node js посредством socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Необходимо реализовать функционал на node js при котором данные введенные в форму на клиенте на одной странице передавались на сервер,потом записывались в базу mongodb.Потом с базы получить обновленные данные всех записей которые мы передали и отправить их клиенту на другую страницу и выводить их там в режиме реального времени,т.e как из формы поступают данные,то они должны обновиться на другой странице.Как это можно реализовать через socket.io?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил такую реализацию:

На странице с формой не нужно использовать `socket.io` вообще (однако можно делать `emit` с клиента на сервер с данными, как второй вариант). Человек заполняет форму и отправляет ее на сервер простым `POST`-запросом. Данные сохраняются в `mongodb` и затем `socket.io` на сервере делает `emit` всем клиентам с этой записью.

```
socket.emit('new_post', data); // data в данном случае это объект с данными из формы
```

Затем на второй странице мы уже используем `socket.io-client`, при загрузке мы грузим все имеющиеся записи, например сервер отдает их при подключении по `socket.io`, либо грузим по API.

Дальше мы просто слушаем событие `new_post` и добавляем данные в DOM.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', () => {
  socket.on('new_post', (data) => {
     console.log(data); // в data лежат данные из формы, которые придут в реальном времени
  });
}
```

Вместо `console.log` нужно будет добавить вывод данных, скорее всего Вы будете использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк, но просто для тестов можно сделать так:

```
const element = document.createElement('div'); // Создаем div в котором будут наши данные
element.innerHTML = `Title: ${data.title} Content: ${data.content}`; // К примеру title и content
document.body.appendChild(element); // Добавляем наш div в DOM
```